# how to add columns into clustering algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science, k-means

i'm working with flask python framework on a data science project , and i need to add selected columns from a csv file in this clustering code, please can anyone help me ? knowing that the clustering code can read the columns, i could save csv file and select the columns from the server side so i just need to add it to this clustering code

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

class Clustering():
  def __init__(self, filename, start_column, end_column):
      self.n = start_column
      self.m = end_column
      self.filename = filename
      self.dataset = pd.read_csv(self.filename)
      self.X = self.dataset.iloc[:,[self.n,self.m]].values

  def show_test(a):
      return "just a test object"+a[0]+","+a[1]
  
  #def  return_x(self):
      ######## return concerned columns of the dataset ########
     #return self.X


  def print_elbow(self, number_of_k):
      # Plot the graph to visualize the Elbow Method to find the optimal number of cluster
      self.k = number_of_k
      wcss=[]
      silhouette_values = {}
      for i in range (2,self.k):
          self.kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init = 10, random_state =None)
          self.kmeans.fit(self.X)
          wcss.append(self.kmeans.inertia_) # Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center.
          # Compute the silhouette scores for each sample
          cluster_labels = self.kmeans.fit_predict(self.X)
          silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(self.X, cluster_labels)
          silhouette_values[i] = silhouette_avg
          print("For n_clusters =", i,"The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)

      print("Best silhouette score:", max(silhouette_values, key=silhouette_values.get))

      plt.plot(range(2,self.k),wcss)
      plt.title('The Elbow Method')
      plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
      plt.ylabel('WCSS')
      plt.show()
      return

  def print_kmeans(self, Optimal_k):
      plt.style.use('seaborn-deep')
      # Applying KMeans to the dataset with the optimal number of cluster
      self.opt_k = Optimal_k
      self.kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters= self.opt_k, init = 'k-means++', max_iter = 300, n_init = 10, random_state = 0)
      y_kmeans = self.kmeans.fit_predict(self.X)
      for i in range(self.opt_k):

          plt.scatter(self.X[y_kmeans == i, 0], self.X[y_kmeans == i,1],s = 80, marker='o', alpha=0.7 , label = 'Cluster {}'.format(i+1))

      plt.scatter(self.kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,0], self.kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,1], s = 100, c = 'black',edgecolors='none', label = 'Centroids')

      plt.title('Clusters')
      plt.xlabel('first column')
      plt.ylabel('second column')
      plt.legend()
      plt.show()
      return ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

Clustering('file.csv',start,end+1).

'file.csv' represents file path.

start denotes starting column number (int).

end is the last column u want to read. +1 to include that column.